# Continue ajax processing after function execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a situation, I need to execute a function but the alert prevent the function execute even when it's after the calling. So I need `llamadaEntrante()` execute before `confirm()`; but can't make it work, any thought?

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {func: 'checkLlamadaEntrante'},
    url: 'https://www.cge.mil.ar/adm_sis/pedirLlamada.aspx'
})
.done(function (data) {
    if (data != 0){
        llamadaEntrante();
        var array = data.split(',');
        conf_id = array[1];
        enEsperaDeConfirmacion(conf_id);
        var r = confirm("Tiene una llamada de "+array[0]);
        if (r == true) {
            aceptaLlamada(conf_id);
            $("#videoLlamada_container").children('iframe').remove();
            $("#videoLlamada_container").show('slow');
            $("#videoLlamada_container").children('div.buscardor_grilla').children('input:first').focus();
            $("#videoLlamada_container").append('<iframe src="https://www.cge.mil.ar/videollamadaapp/default.aspx?conf_id='+conf_id+'" height="410px" width="534px" scroll="no"></iframe>');
            $("#option_aux").hide();
        } else {
            cancelaLlamada(conf_id);
        }
        cortaEntrante();
    } else {
        console.info('no llamaron');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoudl work I think... do you know anything about promises?

```
function llamadaEntrante()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        // put your normal llamadaEntrante code in here
        // doing some stuff
        // and then resolve the promise with just true in this case
        resolve(true);

    });
}
```

So just to clarify...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {func: 'checkLlamadaEntrante'},
        url: 'https://www.cge.mil.ar/adm_sis/pedirLlamada.aspx'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data != 0)
        {
            llamadaEntrante()
            .then(function()
            {
                var array = data.split(',');
                conf_id = array[1];
                enEsperaDeConfirmacion(conf_id);

                var r = confirm("Tiene una llamada de "+array[0]);
                if (r == true) 
                {
                    aceptaLlamada(conf_id);
                    $("#videoLlamada_container").children('iframe').remove();
                    $("#videoLlamada_container").show('slow');
                    $("#videoLlamada_container").children('div.buscardor_grilla').children('input:first').focus();
                    $("#videoLlamada_container").append('<iframe src="https://www.cge.mil.ar/videollamadaapp/default.aspx?conf_id='+conf_id+'" height="410px" width="534px" scroll="no"></iframe>');
                    $("#option_aux").hide();
                } else 
                    cancelaLlamada(conf_id);

                cortaEntrante();

            });
        }else{
            console.info('no llamaron');
        }
    });
```

Comment: It cannot reach "confirm("Tiene una llamada de "+array[0]);" unless the llamadaEntrante() has completed, that makes no sense. What do you mean by the"first confirm()"???

Comment: Whoever did the votedown, can you please explain? This is a perfectly reasonable answer to the "Question Asked"!

Comment: but i dont click in vote down :S ..

The confirm () calls before promise, dont know why but that happens..

Anyway, i have created a "confirm" like a modal, so i create a dinamic box to confirm and works.. at least i can do what i wanted =).